# How I can correctly read txt file in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, encoding, text-files

I try to read txt file with next content:

I using this method to read txt file:

```
public string ReadFileContents()
{
    //this verse is loaded for the first time so fill it from the text file
    var ResrouceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Files/info.txt", UriKind.Relative));
    if (ResrouceStream != null)
    {
        Stream myFileStream = ResrouceStream.Stream;
        if (myFileStream.CanRead)
        {
            StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myFileStream);
            //read the content here
            return myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
    }
```

This method return to me next string with wrong symbols:

How I can correctly read txt file??

Comment: Does it work if you use the entity for the '®'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you showing the text?  Maybe it's the printing code rather than the reading code.

Also, is the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) correct on the file?  I believe the first 3 bytes specify the encoding type.  Are they correct for this encoding?

Comment: That text i am to copy from variable in debuging

Answer (score 0):

Wrong symbols: When reading an ANSI encoded text-file on Windows Phone will cause umlauts, special characters etc. "looking wrong" since you have to use UTF-8 on Windows Phone.